# When orientation change than webview size will change but not smoothly

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-orientation

I have created a WebView programmatically. And changing its size when orientation change. But when i change size of that webview then it will change but not smoothly. how can i make it change size smoothly.

This is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-44)];  //Change self.view.bounds to a smaller CGRect if you don't want it to take up the whole screen


    NSURL * urlStr = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.co.in/"];

    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlStr]];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
}


-(void)orientationChanged {


    UIDeviceOrientation   orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;


    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        if (screenBounds.size.height == 568)
        {
            webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 568, 230);
        }
        else
        {
            webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 480, 230);
        }
    }
    else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        if (screenBounds.size.height == 568)
        {
            webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44,568, 230);
        }
        else
        {
            webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 480, 230);
        }
    }
    else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        //do change in design when ios change
        if (screenBounds.size.height == 568)
        {
                 webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 524);
        }
        else
        {
                 webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 400);
        }
    }
    else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        //Do what you want in Portrait Upside Down
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use animations. 
checkout those links

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5478/uiview-animation-tutorial-practical-recipes
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/

you can use blocks with method

```
animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:
```

or you can use older API with static methods (class methods)

```
+ beginAnimations:context:
```

f.e.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{

    if (screenBounds.size.height == 568)
    {
        webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44,568, 230);
    }
    else
    {
        webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 480, 230);
    }
}];
```

or if you target is >= ios 6.0 you can use [NSLayoutConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLayoutConstraint/constraintWithItem%3aattribute%3arelatedBy%3atoItem%3aattribute%3amultiplier%3aconstant)